# Postgresql : how to find name, conditional_state for a group having different status based on condition

Tags: database, postgresql

In Postgresql database, I am not able to think how to solve below mentioned requirement.

From the below table, I need to show data in format as "name", "state"

**conditions of different states :**

```
|State       |  condition  
|------------|-------------
|COMPLETED   | if for the user all record is DELIVERED
|IN PROGRESS | if for the user at least 1 record is DELIVERED, 1 READY, 1 CREATED
|READY       | if for the user doesn't have DELIVERED and have READY, CREATED
|STARTED     | if for the user have only CREATED
```

**Table name:** customer_order

```
|  user  |  status  |
|:-------|:---------|
|Jack    |DELIVERED |
|Jack    |DELIVERED |
|Jack    |DELIVERED |
|Ravi    |DELIVERED |
|Ravi    |READY     |
|Ravi    |CREATED   |
|Hari    |READY     |
|Hari    |CREATED   |
|Vijay   |CREATED   |
|Vijay   |CREATED   |
|Vijay   |CREATED   |
```

**Expected output**

```
|  name  |  state      |
|--------|-------------|
| Jack   | COMPLETED   |
| Ravi   | IN PROGRESS |
| Hari   | READY       |
| Vijay  | STARTED     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation along with some case logic to figure this out:

```
select username,
       CASE 
         WHEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='DELIVERED') > 0 AND count(*) FILTER (WHERE status != 'DELIVERED') = 0 THEN 'COMPLETED' 
         WHEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='DELIVERED') > 0 AND count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='READY') > 0 AND count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='CREATED') > 0 THEN 'IN PROGRESS'
         WHEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='DELIVERED') = 0 AND count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='READY') > 0 AND count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='CREATED') > 0 THEN 'READY'
         WHEN count(*) FILTER (WHERE status='CREATED') > 0 AND count(*) FILTER (WHERE status != 'CREATED') = 0 THEN 'STARTED'
       END as state
FROM customer_order
GROUP BY username;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=824edb59622069d7b36a7e51592e4c10).